# How to disable iOS Chrome password/credit card autofill?

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, autocomplete, credit-card

On iOS 13 Chrome, when focusing on a text input, a wide gray bar will show on top of the keyboard with only a couple buttons for password and credit card autocompletion even though the input has attributes `type` set to `"text"` and `autocomplete` set to `"off"`.

[image]

Besides being unneeded, this bar doesn't seem to decrease browser's perceived window height, so elements on the bottom of the page are getting cut off.

Edit: it is important to add the bar always shows up glued to the keyboard, even if the focused element is a `<textarea>` instead. This is not an issue specific to my website. For instance, this bar will show on google.com if I focused on the search input.

Is there a way of disabling/hiding that bar?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No; it looks like this bar is not going anywhere anytime soon. I just checked on Chrome (91) for iOS (14.7.1) @JonatanLundqvistMedén

Answer (score 0):

For the fields that are needing no autofill then place inside the desired `<input>` fields `autocomplete="disabled"` not `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Setting `autocomplete="disabled"` did not remove the bar on Chrome iOS 13.3.1. Besides, the spec specifies `autocomplete="off"` as the right way of disabling autocompletion. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#autofilling-form-controls-the-autocomplete-attribute

Comment: does this work? ```<input type=“search” autocomplete=“off” placeholder=“Placeholder” name=“searchTerm” />``` due to the input type being **search** iOS shouldn't pick it up to do autofill

Comment: It did not work. I added more info to the question pointing out this is not specific to `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody here discussed a workaround: [Disable Chrome Autofill creditcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595141/disable-chrome-autofill-creditcard)

by setting the autocomplete to `autocomplete="cc-csc"` it forces chrome to not be able to try and autocomplete it as its not allowed to store that value, unlike autocomplete="off" which chrome can still try and auto fill.  I've tested this and it works.

Comment: It didn't work on Chrome iOS. Please take into consideration this issue might not be related to autocomplete at all. The bar always shows on top of the keyboard on any website, on `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s regardless of the `autocomplete` value, if any. I think one requirement to see it is that one must have a credit card/password saved on Chrome.