# Is it possible with HTML to disable Autocomplete "credit card not supported message"?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill, credit-card

On my server i have not installed SSL (https) and therefore i get this message when typing into an input field.. is it possible with HTML or other code to disable auto credit card so this message will not be shown?

On the image its the black box below the input who says:
Autofill credit card has been disabled due to..

[image]

I have tried autocomplete="off" on both the form and the input with no success.
I guess this message comes from Chrome and will not be shown in all browsers. Also i think i can get rid of the message by disable autofill creditcard in the browser.

But i think that if i disable autofill creditcard on this input.. maby i can get rid of the message to?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595141/disable-chrome-autofill-creditcard is this you looking for?

Comment: @SandrinJoy Perfect! I tried "new-password" and other, but "cc-csc" worked =)